My virtual environment is not activated in google colab
!pip install virtualenv

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/gdrive")

!virtualenv /content/myvienv

import sys
sys.path.append('/content/myvienv/bin')

#!python activate
!source /content/myvienv/bin/activate

!which python
/usr/local/bin/python

I have successfully created my virtual environment. But unfortunately, the above commands do not work to activate my virtual environment. And my codes are executed in the main environment of my system.

Try this
!source /content/myvienv/bin/activate; which python

Each command is executed in each temporary shell.
So when you activate venv, you have to combined commands in one line.

I learned it from here
